# Python-Flask : Module not Found after Installation

Tags: python, flask

I installed flask by the instructions on the page

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/installation/#installation

Now, when I try

```
>>> import os
>>> from flask import Flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named flask
```

This means that os can be found whereas Flask cannot. How could you tell to python, where to find the needed modules?

Comment: How *exactly* did you install Flask?

Comment: And so, you are running python's  interpreter from yourvirtualenv/bin/python ?

Comment: and/or did you 'activate' the virtualenv ?

Answer (score 1):

Flask depends on two external libraries, Werkzeug and Jinja2.

you can check in your Lib\site-packages dir in windows  or  site-packages in other os whether you had installed it successfully

I think you should try to install it again.

it has no matter with the os module